# Making pie chart with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, charts, xlsxwriter

I have a big excel file and I want to make a pie chart according to two columns the two columns are Name and State. If I wanted to use the State as the categories and then the Names as the values how would I go about doing that using the xlsxwriter charts?

my two columns look like this:

```
   Name    State
0  Jeff     MN
1  Jeff     MN
2  Jack     MI
3  Jill     TX
4  Parker   TX
5  Kalic    AZ
6  Kalic    AZ
7  Kalic    AZ
8  Kalic    TX
```

I have gotten it to work but instead of returning me a pie chart with just one category for MN or AZ it returs multiple categories I want it to just get unique State names and then group everything up under that unique State. I dont want it to give me different slices in my pie chart for each entry.

Comment: You can look into this document http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_charts.html

Comment: I actually was able to figure it out, thank you for your insight though.

Comment: Can you add the solution for the next person who has a similar issue.